# How many versions of Blackberry apps we have to make?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

There are basically two issues that are confusing us:

1. Will a Blackberry app made for mobile phones work on the Blackberry tablet? I see that there is a tablet SDK as well.
2. Do we have to make a separate versions of Blackberry app for different mobile phones?

The reason we ask this is because we come from the Android environment where we can use one SDK to make app which will work on all mobile phones and tablets as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BlackBerry Smartphone SDK is different from the BlackBerry PlayBook Tablet SDK.

The smartphone applications are written in Java (RIM's version of J2ME, essentially), while for now, there are two editions of the PlayBook Tablet SDK: WebWorks, for development with web technologies like Javascript, HTML, and CSS, and one that is Adobe Flash/Actionscript/Air based. I think there is also one in development with C++ as a foundation.

You can start with the BlackBerry Developer zone - it covers development for both smartphones and tablets:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/

The BlackBerry Tablet SDK for Adobe AIR can be found here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/adobe.jsp

The BlackBerry Tablet WebWorks SDK can be found here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/tablet/webworks.jsp

Information about development for the BlackBerry smartphones can be found here: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/

For smartphone development, you would probably want to target the minimum RIM OS that would include the most devices owned by your target customer base.

Right now, RIM claims that more than 96% of BlackBerry smartphones can be reached using SDK 4.5 or higher.

RIM keeps an up-to-date set of statistics on this: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp

Typically, if you're targeting recent devices (4.7 and newer), then you don't need to worry about splitting your code to target multiple devices, as long as the UI is written without making any assumptions as to screen size, etc.

If you're targeting anything older than 4.7, then it may benefit you to make two versions - one for touch screen devices, and one for devices that aren't touch-screen. The touch-screen API is introduced in 4.7, and while it's somewhat backward compatible, in our experience, while you need the touch-screen API available for devices that support it, it's best to leave it out for older devices that do not have support for the touch API or the virtual keyboards that come with it.

If you're going to split the code, RIM's compiler does come with a C/C++ - style preprocessor which comes in very useful.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed reply. We do not have any complex app. It is web icon launcher app (app that launches the browser with URL to our mobile site). I guess with such app we do not have to worry about compatibility much. :)

Comment: If we use JDE 6.0.0 for this simple web launcher app, does it mean that all previous versions are supported as well?  If not, is there a way in JDE 6.0.0 to turn on the reverse compatibility?

Comment: No. Typically, the JDE SDK's for smartphones don't come with any backward compatibility promises. You'll need to target the oldest SDK version that you're comfortable with. So, if you're writing to 4.7, it will be compatible with 4.7, 5.0, 6.0, etc. I think that there is a version of the webworks-type sdk for smartphones as well. For a simple app like you described, it may work great. Take a look at the RIM developer zone site for more info.

Comment: One more thing, if we want to create an app for SDK 4.7, we just download JDE 4.7? It this they way Blackberry works?

Comment: That's right. Download JDE 4.7; it'll have the SDK, API docs and at least one simulator with that operating system version on it. You can also download separate simulators, with various OS versions, to test against. But building with JDE 4.7 will guarantee (according to RIM), that your application is compatible with newer devices as well. We do this with all of our applications. We target 4.1 for non-touch screen, and 4.7 for touch-screen editions of our software. And they all work on newer devices automatically.